# Autoresponder Drupal 7 alternative

Tags: email, drupal, newsletter, drupal-7

I'm looking for a module for Drupal 7 which could do something similar what [Autoresponder](http://drupal.org/project/autoresponder) for Drupal 6 does:

I want to send users different email newsletters after their their subscription. Day #1 - email #1 and so forth. And that module should let preset email templates beforehand (something more sophisticated than Simplenews module that sends emails on demand).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Drupal 7 was only recently released, there will be A LOT of modules that haven't been upgraded yet. If the Autoresponder module looks like it would work for your needs, but hasn't yet been upgraded, my advice would be to [pitch in and help](http://drupal.org/getting-involved) upgrade it.

If you're not yet familiar with Drupal development, it's a good way to learn. You can get a good head start using the [Coder Upgrade](http://drupal.org/project/coder) module or by running the same process via the [upgrade.boombatower.com](http://upgrade.boombatower.com/) site. And if you run into trouble, other developers are likely to be very helpful in the [issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/autoresponder?status=All&categories=All), [forums](http://drupal.org/forum/4), and [IRC](http://drupal.org/irc), once they know you're working on upgrading a contrib module.

**UPDATE:** [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/) allows for rich email templates and automated followups. There is a [dev release for Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/854388) of the [MailChimp module](http://drupal.org/project/mailchimp) that might be worth a try.

Comment: I'm too busy upgrading other custom modules and templates and I do not want to hack all the incompatible ones myself. That's why I'm looking for an alternative. If you know one please let me know.

Comment: It's not hacking, someone has to do the upgrade. If you want to use the module, then why not you? And if you start working on it, others might help too when you post an issue into the queue.

Comment: 1. Hacking is a way to write code. 2. There is no "has" or "must" in open source. People choose to be open source contributors or not. And some just use pre-made libraries or modules. 3. I don't want to use that module only, I'm looking for *any* module that suits my needs.

Comment: For a tongue-in-cheek (but also informative) take on the issue of whether to develop a site in Drupal 6 vs. Drupal 7 right now, check out the Lullabot Podcast, episode 90 (and especially the diagram included on the episode page): http://www.lullabot.com/podcasts/podcast-90-drupal-7-are-you-ready